# Animating image array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, animation, jsfiddle

I've come up with this little animation that uses images in an array, but it's sloppy. What I'd really like is to modularize it so that I can use multiple instances of the same function to animate different arrays depending on which key is pressed. Also, I'd like to get it so that the animation stops when the key is released, if possible. I realize that calling all of those variables globally is a big no-no, but I have no idea how to make it work otherwise! Last but not least, I'd like to figure out how to get that last bit of inline script over to the external file and have it still work correctly. Any help would be much appreciated! But please note, I'm a novice with JavaScript, so please try to be as specific/detailed as possible so I can learn from your wisdom! Thank you!

I've created a jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ghQwF/2/).

```
<div id="wrapper"> <span id="jajo"><img id="my_img" src="http://www.mouserunner.net/free_graphics/Web_2_0/Flowers/Flowers_Preview_P.png" /></span>
    <script>
        element = document.getElementById("jajo");
    </script>
</div>


var i = 0;
var element;
var waveArray = ["http://static.spoonful.com/sites/default/files/styles/square_128x128/public/crafts/fingerprint-flowers-spring-craft-photo-420x420-aformaro-01.jpg", "http://static.spoonful.com/sites/default/files/styles/square_128x128/public/crafts/paper-flowers-spring-craft-photo-420x420-aformaro-11.jpg", "http://static.spoonful.com/sites/default/files/styles/square_128x128/public/crafts/tissue-paper-flowers-kaboose-craft-photo-350-fs-IMG_8971_rdax_65.jpg"];
var jumpArray = ["jump0.png", "jump1.png", "jump2.png", "jump3.png", "jump4.png", "jump5.png"];
var foodArray = ["food0.png", "food1.png", "food2.png", "food3.png", "food4.png", "food5.png"];

document.onkeydown = function (event) {
var keyPress = String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode);

if (keyPress == "W") { // if "w" is pressed, display wave animation
    increment();

    document.onkeyup = function (event) { // if "w" is released, display default image
        document.getElementById("jajo").innerHTML = "<img alt='Jajo' src='http://www.mouserunner.net/free_graphics/Web_2_0/Flowers/Flowers_Preview_P.png'>";
    }
} else if (keyPress == "A") { // if "a" is pressed, display jump animation
} else if (keyPress == "S") { // if "s" is pressed, display food animation
}
}

function increment() {
i++;
if (i > (waveArray.length - 1)) {
    i = 0;
}
setTimeout(animation, 1000 / 30);
}


function animation() {
var img = '<img src="' + waveArray[i] + '" alt="Jajo" />';
element.innerHTML = img;
setTimeout(increment, 2000 / 30);
}
```

Comment: I believe you have to wrap everything in an own function. Something like: function myAnimation(waveArray[],jumpArray[],foodArray[],container){// here you put the other animation functions and so on, container should be "jajo" in your first case. Make it dynamic and good luck :)}

Comment: I believe this belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com